# LG G Watch R - Screen has gone dark and will not display anything

Tags: lg-g-watch-r

Yesterday I found on my LG G Watch R the screen was all dark. When I performed a hard reset, the watch did so, but remained with a black screen. I have tried other resets, still black screen. My phone appears to be connected to it. When I take screenshots through my phone and upload them to google drive, they show the screen fully functional.

There have been no other signs of the screen being damaged. I have not exposed it to rough environments.

I don't know how to reset the device with a black screen. I have not enabled debugging on the watch either.

Any help or pointers for this problem? I really want my watch display the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would reset the watch through the recovery. You will loose all the datas on the watch. But the apps will all be re-synced.

1. Power off your watch.
2. Power it on.
3. As soon as you see the LG Logo swipe from the 11 o'clock marker to the 5 o'clock marker.
4. You will see a menu popping up, with two arrows and a circle at the bottom.
5. Press the right arrow button until you see "RECOVERY MODE" in red font above "FASTBOOT MODE" at the top.
6. Press the circle button once.
7. You will see an android figure with an exclamation mark in it. Touch the display once. A menu will pop up.
8. Swipe from 12 o'clock to 6'clock until "wipe data/factory reset" will be highlighted blue. Then swipe from 9 o'clock to 3 o'clock.
9. Then many no's will be there. Swipe from 12 o'clock to 6'clock again until "Yes -- delete all user data" will be highlighted blue. And then again swipe from 9 o'clock to 3 o'clock.
10. When the process is done you will be in the main menu again and "reboot system now" will be highlighted(when not swipe up until it is). Then swipe from 9 o'clock to 3 o'clock again.
11. The watch will reboot...I will take some time...When the watch is started, the touchscreen should be working normal.
12. You will have to do the first setup again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I think the issue relies on the power converter on the motherboard getting to hot and being next to the display adapter two little pins run into the display from there and if you put the wrong charger plug on it, it can get hot and the heat transfers to the port and warps the display port on the motherboard. Mine was on a 2.1 amp 5v speed charger it should have been on a 1amp 5v regular charger. Being a tiny battery only 430mah it charges in 30-45 minutes on the regular charger and I knew this but made the mistake of plugging it in to the wrong charger for my phone... I opened this up and seem this with my own eyes and made this assumption up so correct me if I'm wrong but I worked on a few of these gwr's and they break for different reasons and have several different screen issues... Only one issue out of these are actually lg's faults. Mostly the users fault. I rebuild these models out of broken devices and resell them.